# Action on Quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G =\langle A \rangle \leq S_n$ be a permutation group. The natural action of $G$ on $\Omega$ , where $|\Omega|=n$ is defined as follows:

$f:G \times \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ such that $f(\sigma,\alpha)=\alpha^{\sigma}$ where $\alpha \in \Omega$ and $\sigma \in G$. The corresponding homomorphism is defined as follows:

$\phi : G \rightarrow Sym(n)$, $\sigma \rightarrow \phi ({\sigma})$, $\phi o {\sigma}(\alpha) =\alpha^{\sigma}$.

My question is the following:

Consider any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$. Then $N \leq S_n$ and $G/N $ is a group. **What is the natural action of $G/N$ on $\Omega$ ?** Can we say something even when $\Omega$ is some subgroup of $G$.

Comment: There are no natural actions of $G/N$ on $\Omega$. Consider $G=S_3$, $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$, $N=A_3$.

Comment: What is $\phi_\sigma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of a group $G$ on a set $\Omega$ factors through a quotient group $G/N$ if and only if $N$ is contained in the kernel of the morphism $\phi:G\to \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$, which is the intersection of all stabilizers of the elements of $\Omega$.

In your situation, the natural action of $G\leq S_n$ on $\Omega=\{1,\dots,n\}$ is faithful ($\ker\phi$ is trivial) so the action never factors unless $N$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide any reference for " The action of a group $G$ on a set $\Omega$ factors through a quotient group $G/N$ if and only if $N$ is contained in the kernel of the morphism $\phi$... " ? Or it is easy to see?

Comment: @Jins sure. If you google "universal property of quotients" you will find more information. For example, I found [this note](https://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/universal-property-of-the-quotient/universal-property-of-the-quotient.pdf).

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Comment: What if the action of $G$ is faithful ? (In this case, the kernel of $\phi$ is identity. ) So in this case, quotient is not defined?